# How can I run my custom gradle task in the unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, gradle-plugin

I need to run my gradle task to test basic functional in the unit test:

```java
import org.gradle.api.Project;
import org.gradle.testfixtures.ProjectBuilder;
import org.junit.Test;

public class IwillfailyouPluginTest {
    @Test
    public void applyPlugin() {
        final Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build();
        project.getPlugins().apply(IwillfailyouPlugin.class);
        project.task("iwillfailyou").// what method should I run?
    }
}
```

But I can not find the method to run it. Help me, please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that `ProjectBuilder` is more for unit-like tests. So with what you have, you should only be asserting that a task named `iwillfailyou` exists, is of a certain type, and has the correct configuration.

```java
public class IwillfailyouPluginTest {

    @Test
    public void applyPlugin() {
        final Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build();
        project.getPlugins().apply(IwillfailyouPlugin.class);
        
        assertTrue(project.getTasks().getNames().contains("iwillfailyou"));
        
        MyCustomTaskType iwillfailyou = project.getTasks().getByName("iwillfailyou");

        assertEquals(123, iwillfailyou.getSomeConfig())
    }

}
```

It looks looks you're trying to test the behavior/function of the custom task. For that sort of test, you would use [TestKit](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/test_kit.html).

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;

import org.gradle.testkit.runner.GradleRunner;
import org.gradle.testkit.runner.BuildResult;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;


class IwillfailyouPluginFunctionalTest {

    @Test
    void canRunTask() throws IOException {
        // Setup the test build
        File projectDir = new File("build/functionalTest");
        Files.createDirectories(projectDir.toPath());
        writeString(new File(projectDir, "settings.gradle"), "");
        writeString(new File(projectDir, "build.gradle"), "plugins {" + "  id('i.will.fail.you')" + "}");

        // Run the build
        GradleRunner runner = GradleRunner.create();
        runner.forwardOutput();
        runner.withPluginClasspath();
        runner.withArguments("iwillfailyou");
        runner.withProjectDir(projectDir);
        BuildResult result = runner.build();

        // Verify the result
        Assertions.assertTrue(result.getOutput().contains("someoutput from the iwillfailyou task"));
    }

    private void writeString(File file, String string) throws IOException {
        try (Writer writer = new FileWriter(file)) {
            writer.write(string);
        }
    }
}
```